# Insert row below clicked button

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a way to insert an element directly below a row. My table should look like the following:

[image]

As you can see the following element is inserted below my row:

```
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" data-exists="product2" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm product2">
                                        Add Product2
                                    </button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Below you can find my viable example:

```js
$(".btn.btn-dark.btn-sm").on("click", this.clickDispatcherTable.bind(this))

function clickDispatcherTable(e) {
  let plusButton = $(e.target).closest(".btn.btn-dark.btn-sm")

  if (plusButton.hasClass("product2")) {
    let plusButtonParent = plusButton[0].parentElement
    plusButtonParent.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', `
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="product2" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm product2">
                                            Add Product2
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
            `)
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="float: left;" class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Product 1</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="cpu" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm product1">
                                            Add Product1
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product 2</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="product2" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm product2">
                                            Add Product2
                                        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm product2">+</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product3</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="product3" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm product3">
                                            Add Product 3
                                        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm product3">+</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see the element is inserted on the side and not at the bottom.

Any suggestions how to insert the element below the row?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: This is a css issue not js. You need to either alter the display properties of the td to appear underneath the other td, or simply use divs instead of tabular structure

Comment: Readded the `javascript` tag because **it is** an issue with javascript. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an issue with your Javascript. You were close!

This is the problematic line:

```
let plusButtonParent = plusButton[0].parentElement;
```

You are accessing the `<td>` element. So inserting a `<tr>` before the `<td>` starts would result in something like this:

```
<tr>
  <tr> <!-- this code is added -->
    <td>...</td> <!-- this code is added -->
  </tr> <!-- this code is added -->
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

That's clearly not what you want. So target the parent `<tr>` instead, and problem solved.

```
let plusButtonParent = plusButton[0].parentElement.parentElement;
```

And you will probably want to keep the `Product 2` at the top like in your example. Easy, just change `beforebegin` to `afterend`.

```js
$(".btn.btn-dark.btn-sm").on("click", this.clickDispatcherTable.bind(this))

function clickDispatcherTable(e) {
  let plusButton = $(e.target).closest(".btn.btn-dark.btn-sm")

  if (plusButton.hasClass("product2")) {
    let plusButtonParent = plusButton[0].parentElement.parentElement;
    plusButtonParent.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="product2" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm product2">
                                            Add Product2
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
            `)
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="float: left;" class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Product 1</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="cpu" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm product1">
                                            Add Product1
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product 2</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="product2" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm product2">
                                            Add Product2
                                        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm product2">+</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product3</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="product3" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm product3">
                                            Add Product 3
                                        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm product3">+</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```